# Advice on the best way to go about developing an app for Android and iOS as first project

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform

Sorry if the title wording is not clear enough. I need to deploy a very simple app on Android and iOS for a partner company (app does not need to be in App Store or Google Play) to control some machinery via bluetooth. Interface needs to be very basic and only contain a couple of buttons and some text labels that display some information (and be able to read a QR code).

We are not a mobile development company, thus I don't have any experience building apps like this, but the required functionality seems simple enough to at least look into what needs to be done.

Now, the problem is that I only know C/C++ and Python (moderate experience with the Qt framework) and am not really willing to learn **both** Java and Swift. I might consider learning Swift specifically for a simple project like this, seeing as iOS development is very much tied to their platform, but Java is out of the question. I've looked around and there seems to be a way to write both of them in Python and deploy to each platform, but something tells me it's not really worth the incredible amount of problems that could arise. I need your help with some advice on how to handle this project:

1. Can a cross-platform app be developed with python(or C/C++) and deployed to iOS and Android (thus halving the overall development time) whilst keeping a sufficiently tidy aspect and bluetooth communication?
2. If not, can I develop an Android app using C/C++ or Python without immense hurdles? I'd prefer Qt as i'm already familiar with the framework, but i suppose anything does it.
3. When developing an Android app under point 2, is it possible to see how the app looks like without installing it on the phone for every change in code?

Sorry if the post is too long, am really curios how difficult would a task like this be. I dont want to waste my time learning 2 new languages for just this project nor do i want to end up delaying the partner company with beginner problems caused by my scarce knowledge of a new language.

Comment: As an ios developer I would not recommend trying any cross platform solution for the ios part. You will only have more problems and I think it will take more time than doing it in native way based on some tutorials from the internet. And creating a basic app in swift and basic ui in uikit is not that hard. Look for some beginners tutorials and try going the native ios way.

Comment: @LeszekSzary thanks for the feedback! Should i also get a mac and iphone for this? I'm sure the company would not like paying for an iphone and mac, but i don't want to tell them it can be done on windows and find myself needing to veer development money towards purchases. Some online sources mention VMs and swift sandbox, but it's probably not worth the effort that way.

Comment: Yes I'm afraid you will need a real mac and a real iphone for this. You cannot test bluetooth without real iphone so for sure you need a real iphone device. And you cannot compile the app without macos so you will need a real mac (solutions with VM on windows are not legal).

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't suggest cross platform for this kind of project.  The bluetooth stacks and APIs are going to be tremendously different, minimizing ability to code share.  The UI stacks are completely different.  Really using anything but the native tools on iOS can be particularly tricky.  Python in particular is hard, because its not meant to interact with either platform.  C would be easier, as both Java (via JNI) and Swift (via objective C to C bridges) can call C code.  However the UI layers of the two are so different that it would only be useful for business logic, I would still recommend writing the UI in the native platforms.

If you were going to try and do cross platform, I'd suggest react native and javascript, merely because it's the most mature of the cross platform products.  That said, their bluetooth stack is likely non-existant or poorly developed because its not the type of thing used by many of the type of apps that choose react native, so you'll likely have to dive into the deep end and learn how to make modules.

Given that this is going to be a company specific app not on an app store-  do you actually need to support both OSes?  Or can it be done on company devices of a single type?  Pushing back on that product requirement might be your best bet.

Comment: So far, discussions have been pretty incipient as i decided to research this before accepting of refusing their proposal. Their initial request list mentioned both platforms and bluetooth communication. I'm not sure how much they care for a specific platform, but i figured it's cheaper for them to pay me a couple extra Ks than just going and buying their employees new phones to run just this one app. I have no problem doing both so long i have a rather clear picture of what i'm delving into.